# detecting 2 lines opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image on which I run a dilation, and works fine, now I want to detect two dick lines on it :

[image: DilationResult]

and when run on it the part of code:

```
    cv::Canny(dilationResult,canny,50,200,3);
    cv::cvtColor(dilationResult,dilationResult,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::HoughLines(canny,lines,30,CV_PI/180,500,0);
    cv::cvtColor(mask,mask,CV_GRAY2BGR);
        if(lines.size()!=0){
                std::cout << " line Size " << lines.size()<< std::endl;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
        {
          float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][2];
          cv::Point pt1, pt2;
          double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
          double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
          pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
          pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
          pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
          pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
          angle = atan2f((pt2.y-pt1.y),(pt2.x-pt1.x))*180.0/CV_PI;
          std::cout << "angle " << angle<< std::endl;
          line( mask, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("mask " ,mask);
```

here's the result:

[image: detection result]

what I would like to get is something like this :

[image: the perfect result]

getting only 2 lines that have the same width, and by the way I don't want to use `findcontour` function

any idea how can do this !

Comment: you could try a Sobel filter on the first image (maybe after a median blur), giving the edges at the border between white and black. Then try the hough lines again!

Comment: You draw the output on a 'mask' image that is nowhere defined. Please show the output of the canny function because you run the hough on that image.

Comment: as I said it a part of the code, I got a lot of noise on that picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't get it to work with hough transform, but with the probabilistic version cv::HoughLinesP

with lineDetection_Input.jpg being your linked image
[image: lineDetection_Input.jpg]

```
int main() 
{
    cv::Mat color = cv::imread("../lineDetection_Input.jpg");

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(color, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
    cv::HoughLinesP( gray, lines, 1, 2*CV_PI/180, 100, 100, 50 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::line( color, cv::Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
              cv::Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 1);
    }

    cv::imwrite("lineDetection_Output.jpg", color);
    cv::namedWindow("output"); cv::imshow("output", color); cv::waitKey(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

lineDetection_Output.jpg:
[image: lineDetection_Output.jpg]

for rotated image:
[image]

[image]

and for some different intersection angle:
[image]

[image]

there you can see some lines detected with a slightly false angle that start in the top-right and end near the intersection (close behind), but these might be easily filtered by length or something.

Comment: @ Micka thanks for your answer, but you consider that the lines always have 90 degree which is not the case

Comment: no, the lines are tested in 2° angle steps in my code, can be changed to other step sizes (e.g. 1°), I guess. Tested the same code with rotated image and edited the posting with new images. Try `cv::HoughLinesP` (instead of `cv::HoughLines`), it's really nice =)

Comment: how did you rotated the image?

Comment: GIMP, I also removed the noise at top and bottom of the image because I didnt know whether that's always at top and bottom of the image or whether it should be rotated too.

I guess I musunderstood you, you didnt mean 90° to the image borders but some other intersection angle? Wait a sec, I'll try another image